# Periodical speed increases in git clone

Tags: github, digital-ocean

I was cloning a repository onto a (DigitalOcean) server when I noticed that whilst performing git clones (I did two of them) These were both cloned from Github. I saw some weird behaviour in in my networking graphs: [image: networking graph]

As you can see, the download looks like it's speeding up periodically, but then reverting to the "normal level" quickly. When I checked the specific points in the graph, I noticed that the points are also pretty periodical. There are 6 measurement points before the first peak, 2 during the peak itself, then another 6, then 3 during the peak, then another 6, then 2 during the peak and then another 6. Thus the pattern here is 6-2-6-3-6-2-6.

I than ran git clone again and was saw the same behaviour. Can it be that DigitalOcean is simplifying these graphs in a way (it could just be a regular parabola which they somehow processed) or is there something github is doing to somehow force this behaviour?

Comment: Coud be throttling/bandwidth shaping on GitHub's end as well... Or similarly from Digital Ocean's side. Or GitHub switching between pack files... Or indeed simplified graphs that don't show too much detail and therefore always look jagged...

Comment: It's almost certainly not Git itself, which just reads and writes as fast as the underlying system will allow.

Answer (score 0):

This might have to do with the amount of files being downloaded. When downloading smaller files the overall speed and data usage will be lower then while downloading one big file because the program doesn’t have to switch files.